# For loop body executes with a value that does not meet the loop condition in threaded code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Here it goes a tricky one (maybe not for experts). I'm learning about concurrency in C# and I'm playing around with some dummy code to test the fundamentals of threads. Im surprised about how is possible that the following code prints the value **10** sometimes.

```
Thread[] pool = new Thread[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   pool[i] = new Thread(() => Console.Write(i));
   pool[i].Start();
}
```

Typical output is like `76881079777`. I know is the value **10** and not 1 and 0 because the for loop body executes 10 times (not strictly sure, but I couldn't break C#). I'm even more surprised why this does not throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception in the statement `pool[i] = new Thread(() => Console.Write(i));`

As long as I know, the for loop executes like following:

1. Check the condition ( `i < 10`)
2. Executes the body if condition is true
3. Increments the control variable (`i++`)
4. Repeat

So, assuming that, is imposible for me to understand how the body can be executed with the value 10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `pool[i].Start();`, it does not mean that `() => Console.Write(i)` gets executed immediately. Instead, the operating system gets to decide when the passed method gets executed (this is also called "scheduling"). For instance, the operating system may decide to execute one of your threads after your loop is done. In this case, `i` is 10; so this is the reason why an output of 10 might be possible.

Comment: I didn't even think about that. Now it seems so reasonable. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :)